# How to decode a PDF file to a readable format?

Tags: pdf, encoding, lua, decoding, deflate

I want to decode a PDF file so I can use/edit the elements inside the pdf, I want to use/edit them in Lua so I have to have the readable format.
This is the format I need.

```
%PDF-1.3
...
<<
/Length 70
>>
stream
2 J
0.57 w
BT /F1 16.00 Tf ET
BT 31.19 794.57 Td (Hello World!) Tj ET

endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages ...
```

And this is the format I need to decode

```
...   
 <</Length 72/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
    xܳR35W(貊Qѷ3T04ӳ0PISp
        Ꚛ*ٛڀŤ(hxŦ夫ŧ夨j*Ť 7W
    endstream
    endobj
...
```

Comment: And this is a link with resources you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdf/info

Comment: There exists a library called ePDF based on xPDF which is part of LuaTeX. https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/master/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/lua/lepdflib.cc

Comment: https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/10/30/pdf-parserpy/
worked for me.

https://gist.github.com/averagesecurityguy/ba8d9ed3c59c1deffbd1390dafa5a3c2 worked but failed in some cases.

you can use zlib to decompress.